# What are the main advantages of using core plot in iOS applications to draw graphs?

Tags: core-plot

Can someone please tell me the main advantages of using core plot to draw graphs in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Core Plot is a mature framework that has a lot of flexibility. It can draw many different types of plots and offers many options to customize the appearance of the graph. The graphs can be interactive and support gestures like panning and pinch zoom. You can animate various properties using Core Animation or the animation class built into Core Plot which offers additional capabilities.